# Can't find installed module in my Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-pipelines

I am trying to write mu first Azure DevOps pipeline and I have problem to run my unittests. Here is my pipeline

```yaml
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: 'Build'
    pool:
      vmImage: '$(vmImageName)'
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'
    - script: |
          python3 -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
          python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip3 install setup
          pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: 'Install requirements'

    - script: |
        python3 PoC1/tests.py
      displayName: 'Run unittests'
```

The problem is that it s stopping on unittest located in PoC1 directory with:

`File "PoC1/tests.py", line 2, in <module> import requests ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

After installing all of requirements I have output:

```
Successfully installed azure-core-1.18.0 azure-functions-1.7.2 azure-storage-blob-12.8.1 certifi-2021.5.30 cffi-1.14.6 charset-normalizer-2.0.4 cryptography-3.4.8 idna-3.2 isodate-0.6.0 msrest-0.6.21 oauthlib-3.1.1 pycparser-2.20 requests-2.26.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 six-1.16.0 unittest-xml-reporting-3.0.4 urllib3-1.26.6
```

So it s seems like everything is installed correctly but can t find requests module while running my tests. Do you have any idea what can be issue?

Comment: I think the best place to ask for this question is in 'DevOps' community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing all required dependencies inside a venv, and executing the script outside of it, so you have no visibility of those packages when trying to run the file.
You *could* install the packages outside of the venv, or use the venv/bin/python3 to run the file instead.

Comment: It s not like that after using "source venv/bin/activate" I can run any script using this venv and packages installed in it?

Comment: I believe what's happening is that your `script` section is an isolated process and it does not do the preceding tasks within the venv terminal. It creates the venv but doesn't actually use it. Using `venv/bin/python3` will utilise the packages you've installed in it.

Comment: It seems that you are right. Thanks really much for your help :)

Comment: @Serfer No worries! Glad i could help :)